# Attaching a file to a list item using CSOM

Tags: csom, attachments, file

I'm attempting to use a console application to attach a file to a list item I have created in code. Here's what I have:

```
var attachmentInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
               // attachmentInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pdfPath);
                attachmentInfo.FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(pdfPath);
                using (var fs = new FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Open))
                {
                    attachmentInfo.ContentStream = fs;
                    var attachment = oListItem.AttachmentFiles.Add(attachmentInfo);
                   // ctx.ExecuteQuery();
                   // return attachment;
                }
```

The using statement fails with the following error:

```
Could not find file
```

I have hardcoded the filepath plus the file name into a constant called "pdfPath". No luck. I have searched and found several code examples, but none work. I know I create the AttachmentCreationInformation object, but what do I specifically populate it with? That's the point where I'm getting confused. Does anyone have a working sample?

Answer (score 1):

Folks figured out my issue. The problem was the location of the file. This code worked:

```
var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
attInfo.FileName = StringFile.DestinationFileName;
attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(StringFile.FileAtDestinationPath));
Attachment att = item.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
ctx.Load(att);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

The difference is that I copied the file to a folder on my local (c) drive. The problem was that every example I looked at just mentioned `filepath` nothing more specific. The variable `stringfile.filedestinationPath` refers to the file on my local drive. Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: thanks for sharing!